# Loading shared library into bash terminal

Tags: bash

Is it possible to create a shared library ".cfg" to load a group of commonly used functions to be used at the bash command line terminal instead of making multiple scripts ".sh"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put

```
source filename
```

in your `.bashrc` to execute `filename` in your shell, and put all your functions in `filename`.